# Why do the Dutch Euro coins have a religious inscription on their edge?

Tags: religion, euro, netherlands

The euro coins for 1 and 2 euros allow for [an inscription on the edge of the coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifying_marks_on_euro_coins#Standard_issue_.E2.82.AC2_edge_inscriptions). Each country is allowed to use an inscription of their choosing.
(Euro coins allow for a national side as well, for which each country in the EMU can provide a design).

[image: A stack of Dutch Euro coins]

The Dutch inscription is "God zij met ons", which means "(may) God be with us". It's the only country in the EMU that uses a religious inscription — not even the Vatican does that.

Even though The Netherlands do not have as strong an anti-establishment clause as the USA have, they do not have a state religion.

**Why then do The Netherlands have a religious inscription on their euro coins?**

What were the forces in play that made a nominally secular country repeat the religious slogan from the guilder on their euro?

Comment: Because they're a sovereign country and they *wanted* to put it on there?   Asking *"Why?"* is awfully vague.

Comment: @abelenky I've tried to clarify.

Comment: **Even though The Netherlands do not have as strong an anti-establishment clause as the USA have, they do not have a state religion.** Even though the USA *has* as strong an anti-establishment clause as the USA has (trivially), US currency includes "In God We Trust."

Comment: We  (USA) have In God We Trust due to whoever controlled Congress at the time (1950s  also the time of all the communist scares, Mcarthyism, blacklists) thinking that it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This phrase has been on the edge of the Dutch Guilder since 1816. Aside from religious reasons, a practical reason it was added was to prevent forgery and clipping.

When the Euro came 'round many people thought it might be appropriate to use a more secular phrase, and many op-eds and arguments were written. But especially the SGP was fiercely against this and enthusiastically campaigned to keep it.

The SGP is a fundamentalist Protestant party. They want to establish a theocracy and outlaw "false" religions. Not paraphrasing here; this is literally in their party program ([in this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/14276/11249) I went in to some depth as to why they're still a part of modern Dutch politics).

There was no vote for the design, the minister of finance (Gerrit Zalm) chose it. Why exactly did he choose it? I can't find any clear statements from him about this. Some plausible reasons:

- Dutch politics are very much based compromise and consensus. There's even a word for it: [*polderen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polder_model). Zalm may have simply not wanted to "ruffle any feathers" to maintain a good working relationship with the SGP (and in significantly lesser degree some other parties, such as the Christian-Democrats). This would benefit his own party in the long run in a *quid pro quo* fashion.
- Similarly, removing it might alienate some religious voters, while keeping the phrase was a lot less likely to alienate more secular minded voters.
- Tradition may have played a role. The phrase is from [Romans 8:31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+8%3A31&version=NIV), and the full Latin phrase *Si Deus nobiscum quis contra nos* first appeared on coins in the [Dutch Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_Republic) of 1581 which laid the foundation of the modern Netherlands (thank you MSalters for pointing this out).

---

To explain the mindset perhaps another example of *polderen* might help, for example how the Netherlands dealt with the matter of conciousness objections of civil servants against marrying same-sex couples.

Last year in the U.S. Kim Davis stirred up a lot of trouble about this – it was an affair full of conflict, court orders, protests, and all sorts of consternation.

In the Netherlands – where same-sex marriage has been legal since 2001 – we've also had to deal with this situation. But the political approach to it has been very different. Sure, there have been heated and passionate debates – as there should be – but in the end a compromise was reached where civil servants hired *before* the compromise took effect were allowed to refuse to marry same-sex couples (municipalities still have the obligation to guarantee that same-sex marriages can actually marry though).

Comment: The older version _Si Deus nobiscum quis contra nos_ has been on Dutch coins since the [80 years war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighty_Years'_War). This war is the Dutch war of independence, so this text is not just a bit historical, it goes back to the core of the nation. Also, there is more than a bit of irony in the fact that it combines religion and money, the two chief causes of the Dutch secession from Spain.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks! I actually knew that, but didn't really consider it could have been a factor. I suppose that it's not implausible that it was.